# uncaught referenceError: Finland is not defined in function

Tags: javascript, function

When I call my function I get the `Uncaught ReferenceError: Finland is not defined.`

```
function decribeCountry(country, population, capitalCity){
const countryId =`${country} has a population of ${population} and its capital city is ${capitalCity}`;
return countryId;
}

const countrySpecs = decribeCountry(Finland, 6000000, Helsinki);
console.log(countrySpecs);
```

Comment: Do you sure there's a var named Finland?

Comment: And if Finland and Helsinki are strings please use
`const countrySpecs = decribeCountry("Finland", 6000000, "Helsinki");`

Comment: What @ChangAlex, has mentioned is right, also please check your convention for variables naming why would call it countryId, you can just call it country and in argument you can call it countryName

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the right way to call the function is :

```
const countrySpecs = decribeCountry("Finland", 6000000, "Helsinki");
console.log(countrySpecs);
```

if you do not use double quotes, it will be treated as a variable, not a string.